# How to process data from kafka topic using kafka streams

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I want to run a select query like this on my data on the kafka topic and then publish it on another topic-
select * from table1 where col1='a'.
How to do that?

Comment: https://kafka-tutorials.confluent.io/filter-a-stream-of-events/kstreams.html

Comment: In order to use SQL statements on Kafka Topics you need another feature from the kafka ecosystem, plain kafka does not support that type of usage , you could check out ksqlDB from Confluent or other type vendor solutions suggesting such "drivers"/API for kafka , heard of Lenses.io , guess there are more